# About mcCalendar.SelectionRange limit?

Tags: c#, windows, date, datetime

I have this code

```
 for (int day =1; days >= day; day++)
 {
     onemonth.Add(new DateTime(year,month,day));
 }

  mcCalendar.SelectionRange = new SelectionRange(onemonth[0], onemonth[onemonth.Count - 1]);
```

so these code should get the days of the month and create a datetime of each day of the month to the list.

now. the problem begins when the 
McCalendar.SelectionRange doesnt select from day 1 to 31, it only select from 1 to 30.
its august today and there are 31 days on this month. how can i select all the dates from this month? including august 31.

Comment: its a control, try google it. it outputs the date selected.

Comment: read my answer below. That will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of days in a month by using the following method

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
```

and then run your loop till the number of days you get.

by the way if you have to select all days of current month. You don't need any loops

```
public DateTime StartOfMonth(DateTime dateTime)
{
      return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);
}
public DateTime EndOfMonth(DateTime dateTime)
{
      DateTime firstDayOfTheMonth = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);
      return firstDayOfTheMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
}
private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      DateTime startMonth = StartOfMonth(DateTime.Now);
      DateTime endMonth = EndOfMonth(DateTime.Now);
      monthCalendar1.SelectionRange = new SelectionRange(startMonth, endMonth);
}
```

Comment: still doesnt work. i think the mccalendar is limited in a way. could only select 30 days.

Comment: is it merge calendar? give me the linlk

Comment: it is the normal month calendar found in VS. and it doesn't have any such limitation. Show me the code

Comment: for (int day =1; days >= day; day++)
            {
                onemonth.Add(new DateTime(year,month,day));
            }

            
            //only selects from 1-30 not 1-31 or 1-32//help
            mcCalendar.SelectionRange = new SelectionRange(startofmonth, endofmonth.AddDays(1));

Comment: days has the value 31.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using a "days" variable, in the for loop.
you should initialize it to the number of days of the month, for every month:

```
int days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
```